# Plot Selected Columns in PivotChart from Pivot-Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

My [pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPvA5.png) contains the Sum and % of 'N' and 'Y' queries generated using the PivotTable '% of RowTotal' and 'Sum Values' functions.

I want to generate a **Pivot Chart that Filters for FirstOpenedText and only includes two columns "Sum of # of Queries Issued 2" and "Total Sum of # of Queries Issued".**

Is there a way to plot only the selected columns instead of everything in PivotChart?

PS:

- I tried formatting the table to hide unused columns but the format messes up every time I filter something in the chart.
- I can't plot a normal graph too as I need the Filter function in the graph.

Please help.. TYSM!